# Socket.IO won't work with Express

Tags: node.js

I'm using Socket.io 1.3.6 and express 4.13.1.

I followed the example for express 3/4 on socket.io website:
http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4

On server side:

```
 18 /**
 19  * Create HTTP server.
 20  */
 21 
 22 var server = http.createServer(app);
 23 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 24 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 25   console.log(JSON.stringify(socket));
 26 });
 27 
 28 
 29 /**
 30  * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 31  */
 32 
 33 server.listen(port);
```

On client side:

```
 42   socket = io.connect(ChartServiceFrontConfig.socketHost, ChartServiceFrontConfig.socketPort);
 43 
 44   socket.on('data', function(data) {
 45     // render data
 46     var chart = charts[data.name];
 47     if (chart !== undefined)
 48       chart.series = data.series;
 49   });
```

**Express** just says the following 404 message:

```
GET /engine.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1440667610196-0 404 2.172 ms - 925
GET /engine.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1440667611046-1 404 2.627 ms - 925
GET /engine.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1440667612854-2 404 6.672 ms - 925
GET /engine.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1440667615955-3 404 6.362 ms - 925
GET /engine.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1440667620537-4 404 2.340 ms - 925
```

It looks Express does get that request, but socket.io doesn't interpret requests from http server.
I tried the following code with no luck...:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

I searched around but there's no answer worked for me. So I'm stuck here. Any comments?

Comment: FYI, your code here is not using Express at all.  This is a generic http server example.

Comment: Your client is using `engine.io` but your server is using `socket.io`?

Comment: That app object is an instance of Express: var app = express(); @jfriend00

Comment: It looks so, but I don't know why... The page does use <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/socket.io.js'></script> @robertklep

Comment: There is no `app` object in the code you posted or any use of Express.  That's all I was observing.

Comment: @xiedidan that's not the correct use for `socket.io`, you should use `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` (see the example that you're linking to)

Comment: Please check server side line #22, var server = http.createServer(app); @jfriend00

Comment: I switched to <script type='text/javascript' src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>. The error still exists... @robertklep

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by changing the client side line #42 in my question. 
Socket.IO client doesn't accept 2 parameters, so just use:

```
socket = io.connect(ChartServiceFrontConfig.socketHost
  + ':'
  + ChartServiceFrontConfig.socketPort);
```

Now socket.io connects.